# maximum columns for a fact table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

We have an application that receives an applicant and then retrieves various 'credit type scores' from different vendors for this applicant.

We have a fact table that is over 1000 columns. 
The reason for this is our data analysts have requested a 'flattened' denormalized table that holds all the scores given to us by all vendors.
e.g. vendor_1_score_a, vendor_1_score_b, etc.

This fact table is also fine grained, as each row consists of a single applicant transaction.

My question is, is there a better way to design this fact table for our data analyst team, as we are getting 'too many columns' type errors.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fact table of a data warehouse is usually flattened as you've described.  The retrieval speed is much more important than referential integrity.

You could use a database specifically designed for a data warehouse.

If you have to use MySQL, then creating a Vendor table is a possibility.  You'd have a row for each vendor pointing back to the application row.

Don't worry about normalizing the Vendor table.  Since this is a data warehouse, where you're adding rows and selecting rows, duplicate data about the vendor is acceptable.

Comment: Well the issue is that for a single consumer transaction, each vendor may return 500+ different 'scores'. Thus our 'flattened' table has a column for each score. As you can see, with 3 vendors, thats already 1500 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Do the queries need to see any of the 1500 columns in `WHERE` or `ORDER BY`?  If not (or at least if most of them do not need to be touched by a `SELECT`, but merely passed on to the processing engine), then I would encode the 500 in a JSON string, compress it, and store it in a BLOB.

This will shrink the disk footprint (smaller -> faster).  The application will fetch it and uncompress it into a structure that it likes.

And you end up with only a dozen or so columns.

Comment: Yes, the data analysts must analyze the values of all columns, as they are all detailed 'consumer score' values.

Comment: But will they analyze it with SQL or with some other programming language?